# How to call a function on list to return incremental bits range

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that returns from and to bits in `[from:to]` format.
I am not quite sure how exactly it can be done (recursively?). The expected output is in incremental range of bits. Here is the piece of code to start with,

```
cntlist = [5,1,4,3,1]
def find_size(cnt):
    if cnt>1:
        a = "[%s:%s]" % (cnt-1, cnt-cnt)
        left = cnt-1
        right = cnt-cnt
    if cnt==1:
        a = "[%s]" % (cnt)
        left = a
        right = a
    return a, left, right

newlist = list(map(find_size, cntlist))
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[('[4:0]', 4, 0), ('[1]', '[1]', '[1]'), ('[3:0]', 3, 0), ('[2:0]', 2, 0), ('[1]', '[1]', '[1]')]
```

Expected output:

```
['[4:0]', '[5]', '[9:6]', '[12:10]', '[13]']
```

Note: If size is 1 in `cntlist`, the range will have only one element which will be +1 to previous range's left number.

Comment: Can you explain what "incremental bits" means? For example, `1` becomes `[1]` based on your shown code, and it is unclear where `[5]` or `[13]` come from for the exact same input. And `cnt-cnt` will always be zero for any integer `cnt`

Comment: If size is 1, the range will have only one element which will be +1 to previous range's left number. [4:0], [4+1]=> 5 comes from here, [12:10], [12+1] => 13 comes from here.

Comment: Your function has no reference to the "previous range". You pass in 5, then you return, then you pass in 1 and return. The input for 1 doesn't know 5 was previously provided to the function...

Comment: Yes, that part is something I am not clear about. That is why I mention "recursively?" in the post.

Comment: You dont need recursion. Your function should just accept the full list so you can index it at the previous element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, a simple loop should work:

```
def bitrange(cntlst):
    out = []
    total = 0
    for i in cntlst:
        prev = total
        total += i
        if i == 1:
            out.append(f'[{total-1}]')
        else:
            out.append(f'[{total-1}:{prev}]')
    return out

bitrange([5,1,4,3,1])
```

output:

```
['[4:0]', '[5]', '[9:6]', '[12:10]', '[13]']
```

Comment: I tried, it says invalid syntax.

Comment: Amazing!  how can grasp the OP logic... `still don't get it`.